# What function does RemoteMessage.send() trigger on Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What I really need to accomplish is an instant messaging feature using Firebase.
I've been reading the Firebase Cloud Messaging docs, but I get very confused about the pourposes of the example codes on the server side.

I thought about this solution:

- Send a message on the client app to Firebase via RemoteMessage.send()
- On Firebase, I catch that message and "redirect" it to the message reciever, who is another client of the app.

In my client app I have this code that I took from the documentation (Firebase was previously initialized):

```
        instance.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(senderID + "@fcm.googleapis.com")
            .setMessageId(Integer.toString(messageID))
            .addData("message", message)
            .addData("action", "SAY_HELLO")
            .build());
```

That would be the first part of the solution, but now I'm stuck on the part of the code where Firebase should "catch" the message and sends it to another user.

I was trying to write a node.js function to accomplish this, but the problem is that I don't know what is triggered when Firebase gets a RemoteMessage.

Would you mind explaining me how can I do this?
Any code example will be welcome. Thanks :)

Comment: I found on the docs that to send upstream messages from the Android device I need to use XMPP protocol. Can't figure out how. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370323/how-do-i-set-xmpp-on-firebase